# Lighthouse Field data is not updated for a very long time, what should I do?

Tags: performance, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

Due to a wrong UX design, I have got a very low CLS score. However, I have fixed the mistake over a month ago.

But the Field Data still remains not updated.

What should I do to force update the Field data?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: added the pagespeed-insights tag for you as that uses the same engine (Lighthouse), increasing your chances of getting the answer you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What should I do to force update the Field data?

You can't I am afraid.

However if you want to see your Cumulative Layout Shift data in real time (to catch any problems / confirm fixes early) you can use the "web vitals library" - please see the final level 3 heading ("Tracking using JavaScript for real time data") at the end of this answer.

### What is actually going on here?

Field data is calculated on a 28 day rolling basis, so if you made the change over a month ago **the problem still persists.**

Just because the lab tests yield a 0 cumulative layout shift does not mean that that is the case in the field.

In field data the Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) is calculated (and accumulates) **until the page reaches unload**. ([See this answer from Addy Osmani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722217/does-cumulative-layout-shift-stop-measuring-on-user-interaction), who works at Google on Lighthouse, the engine behind Page Speed Insights).

Because of this you could have issues further down the page or that occur after an amount of time that would cause a layout shift to occur that would not be picked up by automated tests.

This means that if layout shifts occur once you scroll the page (due to lazy loading not working effectively for example) it will start affecting the CLS field data.

Also bear in mind that field data is collected across **all devices**.

### Probable Causes

Here are a couple of probable causes:

#### Screen sizes

Just because the site doesn't show a CLS on the mobile and desktop sizes that Page Speed Insights uses does not mean that CLS does not occur at different sizes. It could be that tablets or certain mobile screen widths cause an item to "jump around" the screen.

#### JavaScript layout engines

Another possible causes is using JavaScript for layout. Looking at your "Time to interactive" and "total blocking time" I would guess your site is using JavaScript for layout / templating (as they are both high indicating a large JavaScript payload).

Bear in mind that if your end users are on slower machines (both desktop and mobile) then a huge JavaScript payload may also be having a severe effect on layout shifts as the page is painted.

#### Fonts

Font swapping causes a lot of CLS issues as a new font is swapped in it can cause word wrapping to change and therefore change the height (and width if the width is not fixed / fluid) of containers.

If for some reason your font is slow to load in or is very late in the load order this could be causing large CLS.

Yet again this is likely to be on slower connections such as 4G where network latency can cause issues. Automated tests may not pick this up as they throttle loading based on a simulation (via an algorithm), rather than **applying** throttling (actually applying latency and throughput slowdown) to each request.

Additionally if you are using font-icons such as font-awesome then this is a highly probable cause of CLS. If this is the cause then use inline SVGs instead.

### Identifying the issue

[Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751471/how-to-find-cumulative-layout-shift-problems-if-page-speed-insights-says-one-thi) (and answer as nobody answered me) I created on how to identify problems with CLS. The answer I gave to my own question was the most effective way to identify the problem I could find, however I am still hopeful someone will improve upon my answer as more people get used to correcting CLS issues. The same principle would work for finding font word-wrapping issues.

If the issue is JavaScript related as I suspect then changing the CPU slowdown in Developer tools will allow you to spot this.

1. Go to Developer Tools -> Performance -> Click the "gear" icon if needed on the top right -> "CPU". Set it to 6x slowdown.

[image: showing 6x slowdown location on the performance tab in developer tools]

2. Then go to the "rendering" tab and switch on "Paint Flashing", "Layout Shift Regions" and "Layer borders". You may have to enable the "rendering" tab using the 3 vertical dots drop down to the left of the lower panel menu bar.

[image: showing location of paint flashing, layout shift regions and layer borders in developer tools]

3. Now reload your page and look for any issues as you start navigating the page. Keep a close eye out for any blue flashes as they are highlighting items that were shifted. I have found that once I spot a potential shift it is useful to toggle the first two options on and off individually and repeat the action as sometimes layout shifts are not as noticeable as repaints but both together can be confusing.

### So do I have to wait 28 days to see if I have fixed the problem?

No, if you watch your CLS score for about 7 days after a fix you will see a slow and steady improvement as people "in the red" disappear from the rolling 28 day average.

If your percentage in the red drops from 22% to below 18% after 7 days then the odds are you have fixed the issue (you would also see a similar drop for people "in the orange").

**The actual CLS number (0.19 in your screenshot) may not change until after 28 days so ignore that unless it jumps upwards**.

#### Tracking using JavaScript for real time data

You may want to check out The [web vitals library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) and implement your own tracking of CLS (and other key metrics), this way you can have real-time user data instead of waiting for the Field Data to update.

I have only just started playing with this myself but so far it seems pretty straight forward. I am currently trying to implement my own end-point for the data rather than Google Analytics so I can have real time data under my control. If i get that sorted before the bounty runs out I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do to force update the Field data?

I am not sure if YOU could do anything to change this data as this data is collected based on **Chrome User Experience Report**, as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report):

> The Chrome User Experience Report is powered by real user measurement
> of key user experience metrics across the public web, aggregated from
> users who have opted-in to syncing their browsing history, have not
> set up a Sync passphrase, and have usage statistic reporting enabled

About your question as to why it is not being updated and in your lab data it has 0 cls but in field data it is not the same, again it depends on variety of factors. Lab data is basically running the report in a controlled environment (mostly your machine) while field data is result of **aggregated data** from variety of users with variety of network and devices and mot likely they will not be the same as you unless your targeted audience is using similar network and device as the one on which lab report was ran.

You can find few similar threads by [searching webmasters forum](https://support.google.com/webmasters/search?q=pagespeed%20field%20data).

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I have tested this on a few different machines and the results are the same.

Comment: @AGamePlayer did you try with throttling network as well?